# Criando custom Toolbar, action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, actionbar

Galera estou criando um toolbar separado para facilitar o desenvolvimento Estou querendo fazer uma toolbar bem simples porem não consigo

como eu quero fazer: http://prntscr.com/cuipex

meu codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFF">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/servisale_blue" />


 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

como fica: http://prntscr.com/cuitno

Comment: Para fazer um toolbar customizado o caminho é esse mesmo, porém  você tem que definir as propriedades corretamente dentro do seu toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão existe um espaçamento no Toolbar de `16dp`, então é necessário usar o método `contentInsetStart` definindo-o como `0dp`. Leia mais sobre [Metrics & keylines na documentação](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#) do Material Design. Veja a imagem das especificações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui refazer seu Toolbar, veja abaixo:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:background="#639DAF"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:padding="6dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="HOME"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="#639DAF"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="#639DAF" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Opa é isso ai obrigado mesmo vou só adapatar aqui para eu usar em forma de botão 
pode responder outra coisa rapida para criar esse botao de login compensa usar imageButton ou criar um shape ou alguma outra forma?

Comment: ImageButton é para caso você queira colocar alguma imagem, desta forma que fiz customizando o TextView já funciona perfeitamente, porém na minha opinião, você pode fazer usando Button mesmo.

Comment: Só lembrando que tem como fazer um `setOnClickListener` em um TextView também. Abraços e boa sorte.